# Inter-rater reliability of two raters for conversation analysis (multiple categories with non-binary values)

Tags: r, agreement-statistics

Two raters have done conversation analysis, coding all the topics in the interaction for multiple participants. There are multiple topics, but they are predetermined. There are two raters, and both have coded all the data. For instance, rater 1 identified that participant 1 talked to another person about Hobbies three times (sports, music, cooking), Family once, and News twice (two different type of news). Rater 2 rates Hobbies as 3, Family 1, and News 1. Which test can you apply for analyzing inter-rater reliability in this scenario? An overall reliability needs to be reported, not per topic.

R code/library would be great! Raters responses are in two dataframes, with column headers as participant IDs and rows as topics, and cells containing counts per topic.

Comment: Take a look at https://hbiostat.org/bbr/obsvar.html